# React Native Button onPress is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Button onPress is not working, the method onButtonPress() is not getting invoked at all. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have a console.log statement which is not printed.
By the way below code is from Stephen Grider's react native udemy cource

below is the code for loginForm.js

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input, Spinner, Field } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  state = { email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false };

  onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    console.log('da');
    this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });

    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
      .catch(() => {
        firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
          .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this));
      });
  }

  onLoginFail() {
    this.setState({
      error: 'Authentication Failed',
      loading: false
    });
  }

  onLoginSuccess() {
    this.setState({
      email: '',
      password: '',
      loading: false,
      error: ''
    });
  }

  renderButton() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <Spinner size="small" />;
    }

    return <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Log in</Button>;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Field
            placeholder="user@gmail.com"
            label="Email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
          />
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Field
            secureTextEntry
            placeholder="password"
            label="Password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
          />
        </CardSection>

        <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>{this.state.error}</Text>

        <CardSection>{this.renderButton()}</CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  errorTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'red'
  }
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: Please post the Button code

Comment: Here it is.
```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = props => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.pressCallback} style={styles.buttonStyle}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{props.children}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Comment: Oops, it was an error in Button code. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind `this` to `renderButton`, you can make use of arrow function which automatically binds `this`,

```
renderButton = () => { //Arrow function binds this automatically
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return <Spinner size="small" />;
  }

  return <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Log in</Button>;
}
```

Comment: The existing code for LoginFrom worked without any changes. Actually I had made a mistake in Button code. I was incorrectly receiving the props.